# Overload the + operator to add an object with int

Tags: c++

I have just learned operator overloading and I am having trouble overloading the '+' operator to add an object with int. I am also not sure with how to overload the '<<' to output an object.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class CLOCK
{
public:
    int h, m, s;
    CLOCK()
    {
        h = 0;
        m = 0;
        s = 0;
    }
    CLOCK(int hour, int minute, int second)
    {
        hour = h;
        minute = m;
        second = s;
    }

    CLOCK operator+(int time)
    {
        CLOCK c(*this);
        c.m += time;
        return c;
    }

    CLOCK operator++(int)
    {
        CLOCK c(h,m,s);
        h++;
        return c;
    }
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const CLOCK &c)
    {
        output << c.h << c.m << c.s << endl;
        return output;
    }
};

int main()

{

    CLOCK c(10, 10, 10);

    cout << c << endl; // should display 101010

    c = c + 10; // should display 10 minutes to my clock

    cout << c.hour << c.minute << c.second << endl;  // should display 102010

    c++; // this should increment hours, time now is 012010
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Please include the errors or unexpected behavior you are seeing.

Comment: "I am having trouble" is a very bad diagnostic. Please create a [MCVE] and specify your issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO! please read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: So.. What problems are you facing, exactly? 1) `cout << c.hour << c.minute << c.second << endl;` `CLOCK` doesn't have such members as `hour`, `minute`, or `second`. 2) `hour = h;` invokes UB, since `h` is not initialized, and you are reading the value of it. Same goes for any further reference of `h`, `m`, or `s`. The single case where those are initialized is if default constructor is invoked.

Comment: Fyi, pretty sure you just wanted `cout << c << '\n';` in `main`, assuming you fix the member assignment, which is backwards in your constructor, and frankly should be using a member initializer list regardless. Doing so would have flagged the problem in the constructor immediately.

Comment: I would advise you have a look at [operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) and check the example provided there.

Answer (score 6):

Your main problem isn't operator overloading (which looks OK). It's that your constructor is badly bugged

This

```
CLOCK(int hour, int minute, int second)
{
    hour = h;
    minute = m;
    second = s;
}
```

should be this

```
CLOCK(int hour, int minute, int second)
{
    h = hour;
    m = minute;
    s = second;
}
```

Ideally, you would use a [*member initializer list*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) for this, which would have caught the mistake of backward assignment during compilation. it is also a good habit to form:

```
CLOCK(int hour, int minute, int second)
    : h(hour), m(minute), s(second)
{
}
```

Had those been backwards, ( `hour(h)`, etc.) the compiler would have puked and told you then what you were doing wasn't right.

Comment: Use initializer list is better.

Comment: @Raindrop7 Indeed it would be, as it would have prevented the backward  member-to-argument association in the first place, catching it at compile-time. It's also just a good habit regardless.

Comment: using `const` qualifier would also make it even better, in my opinion, if later on, the person decides to use either of them inside the constructor body for some reason. any attempt to change them would be caught.